# How do I convert an Excel file with SMILES and IC50 to .smi file?

Tags: software

Not much else to say, I have an Excel file with two columns and I need to create a `.smi` from it.

Comment: Could you at least present a chunk of the data as an example as well the expected text output?

Answer (score 3):

In its present form, your question is a bit vague.

This being said, *if* your spreadsheet contains one column about SMILES strings, a second one about the IC50 values, than 1) simply copy-paste the content of the column about SMILES strings into a text file, and 2) substitute the file extension `.txt` by `.smi`.  So far,  `.smi` I encountered which were processed by `babel` (*vide infra*) did not contain IC50 data, however.

Note 1:  Some programs will recognize `.smi` files because of the file extension or their content.  For others (like [babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page)), you may instruct them that a file  to work with is about SMILES strings even if the file extension is, for example, `.txt` text.  Have a look at their documentation, e.g., [here, on-line](http://openbabel.org/docs/current/) or [here, off-line](http://openbabel.org/docs/current/OpenBabel.pdf).

Note 2: It is legit to have entries about multiple molecules expressed simultaneously in one SMILES string.  An example is exporting structure data from the [CSD](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/csd/) crystal data base with their `conquest` interface (available to subscribers) for entries about co-crystals, or hydrates.  In these instances, individual SMILES strings are concatenated by the `.` (a period on the floor).  Hence, the string `CCCCNC.CC` expresses the simultaenous presence of methyl-butylamine altogether and ethane in one entry.

Note 3, probably beyond the scope of your question: Consider to 1) add headers to your spreadsheet (e.g., structure, above the column of SMILES; IC50 above the column of the IC50 values), 2) export the table as `.txt` file.  Then load this file into [DataWarrior](http://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html) (initial publication [doi.org/10.1021/ci500588j](https://doi.org/10.1021/ci500588j)).  DW is a platform-independent program allowing you to continue to work side-by-side with structure data expressed as SMILES, along with (med)chem relevant data -- some you may compute in the program, some the program may fetch for you  from e.g., Chembl, COD -- and to perform analysis with them.